# rails 3 devise avoid access /sign_in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I use devise for rails 3.2 for authentication.  I've changed the default routes from devise to:

```
devise_scope :user do
    get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    match 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session,
          :via => Devise.mappings[:user].sign_out_via
  end
```

Now my sign in and sign up form is on the root site.  How can I avoid to access 127.0.0.1:3000/signin but grant access to only 127.0.0.1:3000

Answer (score 0):

Want it can't access? Remove it from routes, so user can't access it.

Comment: when i remove it, i will get an error message like this
oMethodError in Authentication#welcome

    Showing /Volumes/Develop/login_app/app/views/authentication/welcome.html.erb where line #6 raised:
    
    undefined method `user_session_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007ffb4d711a10>
    Extracted source (around line #6):

Comment: can you move the sigin form of devise to a partial and in home page, render that partial ?